# How to tell if multiple values already exist in a SQlite3 database, Python3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, discord.py

i'm trying to get my code to insert a new record if none of the regex groups already exist, i've tried many things however i can't seem to get it to work, here is my code:

```
                    for line in log:
                        chat = re.search("\[.+](.+\d): (\w+) \((\w+)\): (.+)", line)
                        if chat:
                            time = chat.group(1)
                            psn = chat.group(2)
                            ign = chat.group(3)
                            msg = chat.group(4)
```

i know that i need this code if a record doesn't exist to insert a new record but can't seem to figure out how to check if that record exists already.

```
                            cursor = await con.cursor()
                            await cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO chat VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)""", (time, psn, ign, msg,))
                            await con.commit()
```

edit:
this is the create code i'm using to create the database

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    con = await aiosqlite.connect("chatfeed.sqlite")
    cursor = await con.cursor()
    await cursor.execute(f"""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "chat" (
        "time"  TEXT,
        "psn"   TEXT,
        "ign"   TEXT,
        "msg"   TEXT,
        "sent"  TEXT
        );
    """)
    await con.commit()
    await con.close()
```

Comment: Please provide a MRE according to the mouse-over info on "sqlite" tag ( https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info )  and some examples of input and desired result based on that database content.

Comment: i added what i believe to be an MRE also how should i show examples of desired result and input?

Comment: You could (as described in the link) provide a `.dump` of the toy database "before" and one "after". The difference would show which and how many lines got added via the queries. I.e. if you show 5 sample insertion-attempts and expect only two of them to insert somethign that would be obvious from the two dumps.

Comment: You probably did some experiments directly on the SQLite commandline. I would e.g. expect some with construct like "WHERE", "=", "OR". Please show th queries you tried and their results.